# IDA pro and compiler-optimized 1-based array accesses in structure

Tags: ida

I know title isn't very clear so here is an example of a code I'm trying to disassemble:

```
struct Inner {
  int field1;
  int field2;
};
struct Outer {
  int some_data[16];
  struct Inner the_array[16];
};

int x(struct Outer* s, int id) {
  return s->the_array[id - 1].field2;
}
```

A compiler fuses all the offsets (positive offset of Inner within Outer, negative offset of -1 index and positive offset of field2 in Inner) into single offset. The complete function code follows:

```
movsxd  rax, esi
mov     eax, [rdi+rax*8+3Ch]
retn
```

IDA and Hex-rays obviously think it is an offset into `Outer::some_data` and not into `Outer::the_array`. Corresponding pseudocode is:

```
__int64 __fastcall x(Outer *s, int id)
{
  return (unsigned int)s->some_data[2 * id + 15];
}
```

Is there any way to manually select which nested structure member is being accessed?

If someone wants to reproduce this example to play with it themselves, that code sample is a complete TU and Linux x86-64 clang 10 or newer produces the assembly code I shown (`-O1` is enough for this optimization). Same source file can be then loaded into IDA as a C header to get the structures.

Answer (score 1):

In the Pseudocode view, try to play with [shifted pointers](https://hex-rays.com/blog/igors-tip-of-the-week-54-shifted-pointers/) to account for the 8-byte offset (`sizeof(*Inner)`)

If you declare s like this:

```
Outer *__shifted(Outer,8) s
```

You might get something looking like that:

```
return ADJ(s)->the_array[id].field2;
```

Comment: It kinda works for this example; -1 gets lost but I could live with that, and I'll be sure to use this. It's only a partial solution though: a) smaller issue - `__shifted` cast will be plastered all over all the callsites, if lucky; if unlucky, same `__shifted` type will be propagated upstream and will require manual overrides; b) this one is much worse - it doesn't work if the function happens to touch not only `the_array` but also some other fields of Outer.